# How to set a cell to 1 if two previous cells are the same in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to use `COUNTIF` to return `1` if two previous cells contain the same string. For example:

```
|  A    |  B    |  C  |
| ----- | ----- | --- |
| hello | hello |  1  |
| world | hello |  0  |
```

How can I do this in Calc?

Comment: Why countif? Just try IF: put `=IF(A1=B1;1;0)` into C1 and drag the formula down...

Comment: Of even shorter, but requires formatting: put `=(A1=B1)` into C1, drag down and set the format of column C to Numbers (will convert the boolean result of the comparison into 1 or 0. respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula `=COUNTIF(A1;B1)` does produce the desired results.  That's because it counts all cells in range A1 that equal B1.  Since the range A1 only contains a single cell, it will either result in 1 or 0.  Documentation: [COUNTIF](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_COUNTIF_function).

However, that is not particularly straightforward, at least not for your example.  The suggestion from @tohuwawohu is clearer.

```
=IF(A1=B1;1;0)
```

Alternatively, use the elegant `=(A1=B1)`, although it requires somewhat more understanding of how Calc works.

Comment: Nice - didn't expect that COUNTIF would do the job, too